# glm formula ":" operator? What does it do?

Tags: r, formula, glm

The documentation says:

A specification of the form ?first:second? indicates the set of terms obtained by taking the interactions of all terms in 'first' with all terms in 'second'. The specification 'first*second' indicates the cross of 'first' and 'second'. This is the same as 'first + second + first:second'.

but what does it mean to take the interactions of all terms in 'first' with all terms in 'second'?

Comment: "interaction terms" in the context of (generalized) linear models is a statistical concept that you'll need to research yourself. This isn't a programming question. If you start Googling, you'll find plenty of resources, but probably you need to take a intro course on linear models.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the statistical meaning of interaction terms, and therefore belongs on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think OP is asking how the formula interface to `glm(...)` works, rather than "what do interactions mean in a glm?" If so, then this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `first` is sex and `second` is eye colour it means your analysis is divided into sex/eye colour categories, so your output parameters relate to blue eyed males, green eyes females etc.  You get this if your formula is `Y~first:second`.

With the `first*second` formula you get on overall parameter (or set of) for eyecolour, another for sex, and the paired factors. You get this if your formula is `Y~first*second`.

If you do `Y~first + second` you get separate parameters for each of the factors.

Actually this is probably a stats.stackexchange.com question...

Answer (score 1):

You can see how this works simply below:

```
df <- mtcars[1:5]    # first 5 cols of mtcars
summary(glm(mpg~cyl+disp,df,family=gaussian))
# ...
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 34.66099    2.54700  13.609 4.02e-14 ***
# cyl         -1.58728    0.71184  -2.230   0.0337 *  
# disp        -0.02058    0.01026  -2.007   0.0542 .  
# ---
summary(glm(mpg~cyl:disp,df,family=gaussian))
# ...
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 27.0833812  1.0251545  26.419  < 2e-16 ***
# cyl:disp    -0.0043138  0.0005157  -8.364 2.46e-09 ***
# ---
summary(glm(mpg~cyl*disp,df,family=gaussian))
# ...
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 49.037212   5.004636   9.798 1.51e-10 ***
# cyl         -3.405244   0.840189  -4.053 0.000365 ***
# disp        -0.145526   0.040002  -3.638 0.001099 ** 
# cyl:disp     0.015854   0.004948   3.204 0.003369 ** 
# ---
summary(glm(mpg~(cyl+disp):(hp+drat),df,family=gaussian))
# ...
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 27.7196970  3.7574472   7.377 6.18e-08 ***
# cyl:hp      -0.0147027  0.0051353  -2.863  0.00802 ** 
# cyl:drat     0.7146769  0.3432173   2.082  0.04692 *  
# disp:hp      0.0003444  0.0001393   2.473  0.01998 *  
# disp:drat   -0.0282752  0.0082855  -3.413  0.00204 **
```

So:

```
mpg ~ cyl+disp is equivalent to mpg = a + b*cyl + c*disp
mpg ~ cyl:disp is equivalen to  mpg = a + b*cyl*disp
mpg ~ cyl*disp is equivalent to mpg = a * b*cyl + c*disp + d*cyl*disp
mpg ~ (cyl+disp):(hp+drat) takes pairwise interactions only.
```

Generally, models that consider interactions in the absence of main effects are not a good idea.